# How to set to open folder with enter in finder?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, folders, filesystem

I want to set to open a folder in finder with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I know it's possible to open a folder with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>↓ Down Arrow</kbd> but I don't like it and I never use it because it's easier to use the trackpad, but enter would be the easiest way.

I tried to set it trough the keyboard shortcuts but I can't do it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Any person new to Apple and Mac would find lot of things un-intuitive or just **forced** on the user, w/o any options to change it.
Or it might be that just many of us had their first experiences on Win/Linux systems.

But just found this plugin to finder [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) which among lot of other options allows you to **ENTER/RETURN** to open a file.

Feeling a lot relieved now! Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

As I know you can not set it to <kbd>enter</kbd> in a normal way (but maybe exist some tricky way) 
but you can change open shortcut by going to `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Keyboard  Shortcuts tab`  from the left window choose `Application Shortcuts` and press `+` to add new shortcut then find `Finder` in Application and choose **`Open`** in `Menu Title` and press any desired shortcut in textbox.

[image]

Comment: There's already a shortcut for this, ⌘+↓.

Answer (score 13):

[PresButan](http://briankendall.net/presButan/index.htm) (Mac OS X 10.4.x-10.7.x): An idiotically named solution to a spectacular UI oversight (rather apropos, eh?).
It also lets you use either the backspace or delete key to delete files.

I can confirm it works (just installed it). Apparently it leverages the accessibility system and uses a daemon to catch the return events.

If you are on 10.3-10.5, you also have the option of using [ReturnOpen](http://www.returnopen.com/).

Answer (score 7):

You could also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en), but it would make pressing return open items even in rename mode. And there are a lot of other places besides Finder where return renames items and other key combinations open them.

[image]

If you don't use a QWERTY keyboard layout, change `KeyCode::O` to `KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN`:

```
<item>
  <name>Use Return as Open</name>
  <identifier>private.app_finder_return2commandO</identifier>
  <only>FINDER</only>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::RETURN</autogen>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::RETURN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Well crud, got halfway through typing this up and then found that **Karabiner doesn't work on Mac OS 10.12+**. They are working on [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md) but it's still pre-alpha.

These instructions still work for 10.11 and lower though:

Karabiner was easier than the top answer here because you don't have to make a System Integrity Protection exception (El Cap).

1. Install app from here: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/
2. Open Karabiner with Spotlight Search (Cmd+Space)
3. In Karabiner search menu (upper left): "use return as open"
4. Check the box
5. Option-click on Finder in taskbar, Relaunch it.

Answer (score 5):

For anybody looking for this in 2018: use [BetterTouchTool](https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/docs/normal_keyboard_shortcuts.html) to make the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key simulate <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>↓ Down Arrow</kbd> key press.

Answer (score 1):

In current 2022 **Karabiner** version,
go to "**Complex modification**" tab > "**Add rule**" button at the bottom >  "**Import more rules from the internet (open a web browser)**" button at the top [image]
Then you should find "**Application specific**" -> "**Finder**" section on the web-page and import it to your Karabiner.
[image]
[image]
Then use the same button "**Add rule**" to select rules you like from that group.

[image]
(Careful with using backspace, you can't backspace when renaming files)

Answer (score 0):

Copy from here: https://superuser.com/a/1758821/1201428

> As for today the simple solution is:
>
> 1. Install Karabiner-Elements: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/installation/
> 2. Add complex modification rule:
>
>    a) Automatically - one click import from official rules site: https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#finder_improved_navigation
>
>    b) Or manualy - add code into to complex modifications:
>
> ```
> {
>  "title": "Finder: enter -> open, f2 -> rename",
>  "rules": [
>    {
>      "description": "Use Return as Open if not renaming file",
>      "manipulators": [
>        {
>          "conditions": [
>            {
>              "bundle_identifiers": [
>                "^com.apple.finder"
>              ],
>              "type": "frontmost_application_if"
>            },
>            {
>              "type": "variable_unless",
>              "name": "onedit",
>              "value": 1
>            }
>          ],
>          "from": {
>            "key_code": "return_or_enter",
>            "modifiers": {
>              "optional": [
>                "any"
>              ]
>            }
>          },
>          "to": [
>            {
>              "key_code": "o",
>              "modifiers": [
>                "right_command"
>              ]
>            }
>          ],
>          "type": "basic"
>        }
>      ]
>    },
>    {
>      "description": "Use Return to finish renaming when onedit=1",
>      "manipulators": [
>        {
>          "conditions": [
>            {
>              "bundle_identifiers": [
>                "^com.apple.finder"
>              ],
>              "type": "frontmost_application_if"
>            },
>            {
>              "name": "onedit",
>              "type": "variable_if",
>              "value": 1
>            }
>          ],
>          "from": {
>            "key_code": "return_or_enter",
>            "modifiers": {
>              "optional": [
>                "any"
>              ]
>            }
>          },
>          "to": [
>            {
>              "key_code": "return_or_enter"
>            },
>            {
>              "set_variable": {
>                "name": "onedit",
>                "value": 0
>              }
>            }
>          ],
>          "type": "basic"
>        }
>      ]
>    },
>    {
>      "description": "Use F2 as Rename and set onedit",
>      "manipulators": [
>        {
>          "type": "basic",
>          "from": {
>            "key_code": "f2"
>          },
>          "to": [
>            {
>              "key_code": "return_or_enter"
>            },
>            {
>              "set_variable": {
>                "name": "onedit",
>                "value": 1
>              }
>            }
>          ],
>          "conditions": [
>            {
>              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
>              "bundle_identifiers": [
>                "^com.apple.finder"
>              ]
>            }
>          ]
>        }
>      ]
>    }
>  ]
> }
> ```
>
> The original answer is posted here: https://superuser.com/questions/307048/making-the-backspace-key-go-to-the-previous-folder-in-finder/1636251#1636251

Answer (score -3):

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> serves as an <kbd>Enter</kbd>  key

Also enabling voice over for when you need to navigate, helps a lot too

Comment: *ctrl+alt+space serves as an Enter button* except that it doesn't (at least not on my Mac). Also, the OP explicitly asks for enabling the Enter button.