# Enter/Return key as CMD + O

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set to open folder with enter in finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/how-to-set-to-open-folder-with-enter-in-finder)

Hi,

I've been using mac for quite some time now, but my problem is that in my daily job I normally use a Windows PC (which require switching between keyboard shortcuts).

now I've become very familiar with all the Mac shortcuts and keys and find it very handy to use (even easier than the shortcuts on Windows).

But one thing keeps bothering me, when I browse through my folders which I normally have in "Grid View" I can't use enter/return to access a folder, but have to use CMD + O.

I find this very annoying because who changes names of folders and files more often then opening one?

and I know this might be the mac way, but is there any possible solution/program to let the enter/return key act as CMD + 0, not looking for a Keyboard Remapping tool.

Kind Regards,
SterAllures

Comment: same question as http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/how-to-set-to-open-folder-with-enter-in-finder

Comment: couldn't find that when I was writing my question, will look through it.